# How do I build the Monero source for OpenBSD?

Tags: build, openbsd

How would openbsd users go about building the monero source? There are no builds currently

Answer (score 2):

Build instructions are on the main repository's main README.md page:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero#on-openbsd

As this is bound to change, and that location will always be the most up-to-date of anything, I don't feel it's appropriate to walk through the steps here.